# Count how many times an element appears in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array

```
let arr = ["hello","Hey","Moon","Hey,"Turtle"];
```

I need to count how many times an element appears in the array.
the result need to be like this:

```
"Hello":1
"hey":2
"Moon":1
"Turtle":1
```

Thanks

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple - use `reduce` like so to return an object:

```js
let arr = ["hello", "Hey", "Moon", "Hey", "Turtle"];

const res = arr.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a), {});

console.log(res);
```

Do note that order won't be guaranteed.

Comment: No problem @BaruchMashasha, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to aggregate lists to single values.

```js
var arr = ["hello", "Hey", "Moon", "Hey", "Turtle"];

function checkCount(list, itemToFind) {
  return list.reduce(function(count, item) {
    return count + (item === itemToFind ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(checkCount(arr, "Hey"));
```

You can also return an object that contains each property and how many times it has been found so far.

```js
var arr = ["hello", "Hey", "Moon", "Hey", "Turtle"];

function checkCount(list) {
  return list.reduce(function(result, item) {
    result[item] = item in result ? result[item] + 1 : 1;
    return result;
  }, {});
}

console.log(checkCount(arr));
```